# Save and stay in the same page using Ctrl+button

Tags: angularjs

using html and angular js ,when i click a save button it has to save and display another page ,but when click Ctrl+save button it has to remain in the same page. please get me answer using ng directives in html page.

Comment: I can see the `Ctrl` button . But I am not able to see any `save` button in my keyboard? which type of keyboard you are using?

Comment: Not such special keyboard as u thought, i have mentioned in question using html and angular js, so think about button in html page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand right, what you want is to have different behaviors whether the ctrl key is pressed while clicking on your button. You can achieve that by checking the click event like in this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Freego/mL5aqf7p/2/

Basically what you need to do is pass the event in your ng-click in the HTML and use it in your JS controller

HTML :

```
<button ng-click="save($event)">Save</button>
```

JS :

```
  $scope.save=function($event){
    if($event.ctrlKey){
       alert("ctrl key is pressed");
    }else{
       alert("ctrl key is not pressed");
    }
  }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank u so much sir, u gave me the exact answer, thank you so much :)